# Django: Is it wise to prefetch when you only need a fraction of the queryset?

Tags: python, django, prefetch

I have the following statement which prefetches the cousin objects related to each user and then slices the queryset to get the last 10 elements:

```py
subquery = (
    Message.objects.values("conversation_id")
    .annotate(latest=Max("id"))
    .values("latest")
        )
latest_message = Prefetch(
    "messages",
    queryset=Message.objects.filter(pk__in=Subquery(subquery)),
    to_attr="latest_message",
)
Conversation.objects.prefetch_related(latest_message)[:10]
```

Is it wise to prefetch in this case? I think the api might be doing a lot more calculating than required specially if we have 1000 users or more.

And as a follow up: when is it a good idea to prefetch?

Comment: Would you ever be fetching all 1000 users in 1 query though? Some pagination would help there. How many cousins does an average user have?

Comment: Well, the above was just an example. In reality I am getting Conversations and their latest messages, Conversations can there be many, like 200+, and each may have 1000+ messages.

Comment: I think this use-case would probably call for some client-side JS that dynamically loads the latest messages for each conversation. You would put some additional load on your application/DB but the user experience would be greatly improved as the initial page load would just return the last 10 conversations

Comment: Indeed. I also did some testing and found out django slices first.